# Error in running truffle test

Tags: solidity, truffle, error

```
D:\Truffle Projects\payable>truffle test

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\First.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\First.sol
> Compiling .\test\TestFirst.sol

TypeError: Using ".value(...)" is deprecated. Use "{value: ...}" instead.
  --> /D/Truffle Projects/payable/test/TestFirst.sol:15:9:
   |
15 |         meta.receivePayment.value(2 ether)();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.2.4 (core: 5.2.4)
Node v14.16.0
```

This is my code:
First.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract First {
    function receivePayment() public payable {
        
    }
    
      function checkBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

TestFirst.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/First.sol";

contract TestFirst {

    uint public initialBalance = 10 ether;


    function testAge() public {
        First meta = First(DeployedAddresses.First());
        meta.receivePayment.value(2 ether)();

        Assert.equal(meta.checkBalance(), 2 ether, "Value should be equal to 2 ether");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Try  .receiverPayment({value: 2 ether});

Comment: And those calls are async, u need to use wait before any calling to a contract method